# global variable in java script pass value from inside to outside the function

Tags: javascript, function, global

**how pass the value from inside to outside the function so that i can use it.. ...**

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script>
            var globe;
            var echo=globe;
            function check(){
                this.globe=90;  
                alert(echo); 
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href='javascript:;' onclick='check();' >open</a>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made the variable global so it is already available inside the function. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/c9ma7wvf/5/)

The issue with the above code is you are assigning value and assuming it as a reference.

```
var globe;
var echo=globe;
```

Assigns to echo only the current value of globe and not the reference.

```
this.globe=90;
```

when you change the value of globe it will not reflect on echo.